# Comparison of two Terms

Tags: prolog

Can someone tell me whats going wrong in this code!

```
testit :- read(Term1),  
            read(Term2),  
    (Term1 == Term2) ->  
    write(Term1);  
        write(Term2).
```

---

```
?- testit.  
7.  
8.  
_L139.  
true.  
____
```

How I can print the value of Term2 in else part.???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(;)/2 has a different operator precedence than you seem to think. Use parentheses to get the intended nesting:

```
testit :-
        read(Term1),
        read(Term2),
        (   Term1 == Term2 ->
            write(Term1)
        ;   write(Term2)
        ).
```

Comment: Thank you. and you are right that I was not clear with (;)/2.